# Keep selected higlight in textarea after event onclick [javascript]

Tags: javascript

```js
function $(e){return document.querySelector(e)}
$('#text').onclick = () => {
   let e=this.event||window.event;
   let target=e.target||e.srcElement;
   const a = $('#alltext').value==''?'':'\n';
   let custom;
   let cnt =target.textContent;
   let txtarea = $("#alltext");
   let st = txtarea.selectionStart; // awal text yang diselect
   let fi = txtarea.selectionEnd; // ahkir text yang diselect
   let tx = txtarea.value; // value dari textarea
   let sel = tx.substring(st, fi);
   let arr = sel.split("\n");
   var s = arr.map(function(x) {
   return '+'+x+'+'
})
   var newText=tx.substring(0, st)+""+s+""+tx.substring(fi, tx.length);
    txtarea.value=newText
}
```

```html
    <textarea id="alltext" autocomplete="off" rows="2">
    *test*
    </textarea>
    <ol id="text">
      <li>plus</li>
    </ol>
```

so when i select *test* and click the word -- plus -- it will be *+test+*

but i want the blue higlight when i select *test* keep in *test* after event onclick button word -- plus --

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a function `resetSelection` and call it at the end of event handler.

1. In following example, I have saved the `currentSelection` in an object.
2. And passed the `currentSelection` object to a function which maintains the selection. Note that I had to add an offset of 1 to take care of added `+` sign

```js
function $(e){return document.querySelector(e)}
$('#text').onclick = () => {
   let currentSelection = {
    start: $('#alltext').selectionStart,
    end: $('#alltext').selectionEnd
   };
   
   let e=this.event||window.event;
   let target=e.target||e.srcElement;
   const a = $('#alltext').value==''?'':'\n';
   let custom;
   let cnt =target.textContent;
   let txtarea = $("#alltext");
   let st = txtarea.selectionStart; // awal text yang diselect
   let fi = txtarea.selectionEnd; // ahkir text yang diselect
   let tx = txtarea.value; // value dari textarea
   let sel = tx.substring(st, fi);
   let arr = sel.split("\n");
   var s = arr.map(function(x) {
   return '+'+x+'+'
})
   var newText=tx.substring(0, st)+""+s+""+tx.substring(fi, tx.length);
    txtarea.value=newText
    
    resetSelection(currentSelection);
}

const resetSelection = (selection) => {
  $('#alltext').setSelectionRange(selection.start + 1, selection.end + 1);
  $('#alltext').focus();
}
```

```html
<textarea id="alltext" autocomplete="off" rows="2">
    *test*
    </textarea>
    <ol id="text">
      <li>plus</li>
    </ol>
```